# HTTP request to post a wav file for WIT.ai API

Tags: ajax, file, curl, post, wit.ai

WIT.ai HTTP tutoral has the following curl requset: `$ curl -XPOST 'https://api.wit.ai/speech?v=20141022' \
   -i -L \
   -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
   -H "Content-Type: audio/wav" \
   --data-binary "@sample.wav"`
I was trying to translate it into jQuery Ajax:

```
function sendWav(){
var data = new FormData();
data.append('file',$('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
//alert(JSON.stringify(data));
$.ajax({

    url: 'https://api.wit.ai/speech?v=20141022',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
    'access_token': 'token',
    'Content-Type': 'audio/wav',data},
    processData: false,
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        alert("Success");
        //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        //process the JSON data etc
    },
    error: function(xhr,textStatus,err) {
       alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
       alert("responseText: "+ xhr.responseText);
       alert("status: " + xhr.status);
       alert("text status: " + textStatus);
       alert("error: " + err);}

});
```

}

It gives an error: readyState: 4, status: 404. I've checked url it alive.
Any help would highly appreciated!